# Moving points across a screen using PIL

Tags: python, class, python-imaging-library

I wrote a sample code to draw a set of points in a black background. What i would like to do is to take one point and move it along specific set of coordinates. I would also like to calculate the time taken for one point to move from one coordinate to another. I am really stuck with the implementation. Any suggestion will be appreciated?

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont, ImageChops
from random import randrange
import time
class ImageHandler(object):                  #
    reso_width = 100
    reso_height = 100
    radius = 5

    def __init__(self,width,height,spot_lightradius = 5):
        self.reso_width = width                                         
        self.reso_height = height
        self.radius = spot_lightradius

    def get_image_spotlight(self,set_points):
        image,draw = self.get_black_image()
        for (x,y) in set_points:
            draw.ellipse((x-self.radius,y-self.radius,x+self.radius,y+self.radius),fill = 'white')
        image.show("new_image")
        return image

    def get_black_image(self):
        image = Image.new('RGBA',(self.reso_width,self.reso_height),"black")
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw((image))
        return image,draw


counter = 1
hi =  ImageHandler(1000,1000)
points = [(52,700)]
img = hi.get_image_spotlight(points)
time.sleep(500)
```

Comment: I don't understand why this is down voted! What i wanted was to input some random coordinates and make the spot move across the coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

PIL is used to create or manipulate static images. It looks like you want to do some animation. For this, other libraries are more useful, such as [PyGame](http://PIL%20is%20used%20to%20create%20or%20manipulate%20static%20images.%20It%20looks%20like%20you%20want%20to%20do%20some%20animation.%20For%20this,%20other%20libraries%20are%20more%20useful,%20such%20as%20PyGame%20(https://www.pygame.org/wiki/GettingStarted)). (if you want to use Python) or the [JavaScript Canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial) in a browser, if you are OK with JavaScript.

Also, your wish to *'calculate the time taken for one point to move from one coordinate to another'* is a bit vague. As the programmer, you can determine yourself how fast a point should move across the screen ;-)